# iOS UICollectionView special cell order

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a simple collection view with 5 elements.
The default order of the cells looks like this:
[image]

I wanna know if it's possible to change the padding\order of the cells to get result like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you *always* have 5 items?

Comment: Don't put the solution in your answer. Please add it as a separate answer.

Comment: Ok... thanks will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I've created a subclass of UICollectionView named "CenteringCollectionView" and with a few calculations of the sections I made it!

The .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class CenteringCollectionView;
@protocol CenteringCollectionViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)collectionView:(CenteringCollectionView *)collectionView didDequeueReusableCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end

@interface CenteringCollectionView : UICollectionView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataSourceArr;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CenteringCollectionViewDelegate> delegateCenteringCollection;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
#import "CenteringCollectionView.h"

@interface CenteringCollectionView () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable long elementsInRow;
@property (nonatomic, assign) long elementsInRowInitialValue;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString *cellIdentifier;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cellRelativeSize; // 0..1
@property (nonatomic, assign) long numOfSections;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable BOOL autoResize; // *** If we want auto resize - we need to set the height constraint of the collection view in size of 1 line only even if we have more than 1 line (section).
@property (nonatomic, assign)IBInspectable CGFloat heightMiddleSpacing;
@property (nonatomic, assign) long cellSize;
//@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat verticalTopInset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat initialHeightConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSLayoutConstraint *selfHeightConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat cellSpacing;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldReloadUIElements;

// UI IBInspectable

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBInspectable UIColor *runtimeColor;

@end

static long const maxElementsInRowDefault = 3;

@implementation CenteringCollectionView

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        self.elementsInRow = maxElementsInRowDefault; // will get the default value if not stored value in storyboard
        self.elementsInRowInitialValue = self.elementsInRow;
        self.cellRelativeSize = 0.5;
        self.initialHeightConstraint = -1;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setDataSourceCount:(long)dataSourceCount
{
    if (dataSourceCount == _dataSourceCount)
    {
        return;
    }

    _dataSourceCount = dataSourceCount;
    self.shouldReloadUIElements = YES;
    self.elementsInRow = MIN(self.elementsInRowInitialValue, self.dataSourceCount);
    self.numOfSections = ceil((CGFloat)self.dataSourceCount / (CGFloat)self.elementsInRow);

    CGFloat selfHeight = [self handleAutoResizeAndReturnTheNewHeightIfNeeded];
    CGFloat selfWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame);

    CGFloat cellWidth = (selfWidth / self.elementsInRow) * self.cellRelativeSize;
    CGFloat cellHeight = (selfHeight / self.numOfSections) * self.cellRelativeSize;

    self.cellSize = MIN(cellWidth, cellHeight);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self setCollectionView];
        [self reloadData];
    });
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.elementsInRowInitialValue = self.elementsInRow;
    [self handleUIelementsIBInspectable];
}

-(void)handleUIelementsIBInspectable
{
    if (self.runtimeColor)
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:self.runtimeColor];
    }
}

-(CGFloat)handleAutoResizeAndReturnTheNewHeightIfNeeded
{
    if (self.autoResize)
    {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in [self constraints])
        {
            if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight)
            {
                if (self.initialHeightConstraint == -1) // not set yet
                {
                    self.initialHeightConstraint = constraint.constant;
                }

                if (!self.selfHeightConstraint)
                {
                    self.selfHeightConstraint = constraint;
                }


                CGFloat newHeight = self.initialHeightConstraint * self.numOfSections;
                constraint.constant = newHeight;

                if (self.bounds.size.height != newHeight)
                {
                    CGRect frame = self.bounds;
                    frame.size.height = newHeight;
                    [self setBounds:frame];
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.superview layoutIfNeeded];
                    [self layoutIfNeeded];
                });

                return newHeight;
            }
        }
    }

    return CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);
}

-(long)numOfSpacesInRow
{
    return self.elementsInRow + 1;
}

-(long)numOfSpacesBetweenLines
{
    return self.numOfSections + 1;
}

-(void)setCellRelativeSize:(CGFloat)cellRelativeSize
{
    _cellRelativeSize = MAX(0, MIN(cellRelativeSize, 1));
}

-(void)setCollectionView
{
    [self reloadData];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    CGFloat horizontalCellSpacing = ((CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - (self.cellSize * self.elementsInRow)) / self.numOfSpacesInRow);
    CGFloat verticalCellSpacing = (CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - (self.numOfSections * self.cellSize)) / self.numOfSpacesBetweenLines;

    self.cellSpacing = MAX(MIN(horizontalCellSpacing, verticalCellSpacing), 0);
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:self.cellSpacing];
    [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:self.cellSpacing];
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [self setCollectionViewLayout:layout];

    self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollEnabled = NO;

    if (!self.delegate)
    {
        self.delegate = self;
        self.dataSource = self;
    }
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.cellSize, self.cellSize);
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    BOOL isLastSection = (section == self.numOfSections - 1);
    if (isLastSection == NO)
    {
        return self.elementsInRow;
    }
    else
    {
        long numOfLeftItemsInLastRow = self.dataSourceCount % self.elementsInRow;
        if (numOfLeftItemsInLastRow == 0)
        {
            return self.elementsInRow;
        }
        else
        {
            return  numOfLeftItemsInLastRow;
        }
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.delegateCenteringCollection respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:didDequeueReusableCell:indexPath:)])
    {
        [self.delegateCenteringCollection collectionView:self didDequeueReusableCell:cell indexPath:[self indexPathWithoutSectionsFrom:indexPath]];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.delegateCenteringCollection respondsToSelector:@selector(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:cell:)])
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *selectedCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.delegateCenteringCollection collectionView:self didSelectItemAtIndexPath:[self indexPathWithoutSectionsFrom:indexPath] cell:selectedCell];
    }
}

-(NSIndexPath *)indexPathWithoutSectionsFrom:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    long sectionNum = indexPath.section;
    long rowNum = sectionNum * self.elementsInRow + indexPath.row;
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNum inSection:0];
    return newIndexPath;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return self.numOfSections;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.shouldReloadUIElements == NO)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (self.autoResize && self.selfHeightConstraint)
        {
            BOOL isTheFirstCellInTheLastSection = (indexPath.section == self.numOfSections - 1) && indexPath.row == 0;
            if (isTheFirstCellInTheLastSection)
            {
                CGFloat newHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(cell.frame) + self.cellSpacing;

                self.selfHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight;

                if (self.bounds.size.height != newHeight)
                {
                    CGRect frame = self.bounds;
                    frame.size.height = newHeight;
                    [self setBounds:frame];
                }

                [self.superview layoutIfNeeded];
                [self layoutIfNeeded];
            }
        }
    });
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.shouldReloadUIElements == NO)
    {
        return collectionView.contentInset;
    }

    NSInteger cellsCount = [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
    CGFloat horizontalInset = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - (cellsCount * self.cellSize) - ((cellsCount - 1) * self.cellSpacing)) * 0.5;
    horizontalInset = MAX(horizontalInset, 0.0);

    BOOL isLastSection = (section == self.numOfSections - 1);

    CGFloat verticalTopInset = self.cellSpacing;

    CGFloat verticalBottomInset = verticalTopInset;

    if (section == 0 && isLastSection == NO)
    {
        if (self.heightMiddleSpacing)
        {
            verticalBottomInset += self.heightMiddleSpacing;
        }
        verticalBottomInset /= 2;
    }

    if (section > 0)
    {
        if (self.heightMiddleSpacing)
        {
            verticalTopInset += self.heightMiddleSpacing;
        }
        verticalTopInset /= 2;

        if (isLastSection == NO)
        {
            if (self.heightMiddleSpacing)
            {
                verticalBottomInset += self.heightMiddleSpacing;
            }
            verticalBottomInset /= 2;
        }
    }

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(verticalTopInset, horizontalInset, verticalBottomInset, horizontalInset);
}

@end
```

And to make it work, all we need to do in the parent view is:

```
self.collectionView.delegateCenteringCollection = self;
self.collectionView.dataSourceCount = 5; // Or whatever number we want!
```

**In the storyboard:** we need to create collectionView of this class and set the "elements in row" value, also set the "Cell Identifier" and the "Cell relative size" between 0 to 1 (the "Cell relative size" value: will calculate the cell size & paddings according to the collectionView width & height).
And at last - set "autoResize" to "true" if you want that the collection view will resize its own height constraint(if exist) automatically according to the number of rows. If we set "autoResize" to true, the height constraint that we set to the collectionView will determine the height of a single row. If our collectionView should grow for example to 3 rows, it will multiple our collectionview height constraint by 3.

And it works like a charm!

Comment: Not sure why you update your question with the solution you got from our answers , but in complete code and removed the answer mark from the initial solution that led you to this. You still use **insetForSectionAtIndex** as I provided in my answer before you unmarked it as the correct answer, only difference here is you have this pasted complete customized code for your specific needs, not the question per se. The only matter to the question for the insets are that single delegate call, everything else is unrelated.

Answer (score 5):

## Option 1: (Clean option)

You should have **2 sections**.

- Section 1 with 3 cells
- Section 2 with 2 cells

You can then **[adjust the inset](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617718-collectionview?language=objc)** with `collection​View(_:​layout:​inset​For​Section​At:​)` for the section you want to adjust. (in this case, section 2)

> If you do not implement this method, the flow layout uses the value in
>   its section​Inset property to set the margins instead. Your
>   implementation of this method can return a fixed set of margin sizes
>   or return different margin sizes for each section.
>
> Section insets are
>   margins applied only to the items in the section. They represent the
>   distance between the header view and the first line of items and
>   between the last line of items and the footer view. They also indicate
>   they spacing on either side of a single line of items. They do not
>   affect the size of the headers or footers themselves.

## Option 2: (Spaghetti option, but good to know)

Create a custom subclass for section 2 items, where you can customize the inset of the actual content for the `UICollectionViewCell` `contentView` subviews.

Then in section 2, return your customized cell.

Answer (score 4):

To do this, you may need to write a custom layout. Check out the [Collection View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1) for more information.

The default (flow) layout will always lay the cells out in this pattern:

[image]

Comment: No need to complicate things to write custom layouts, check my answer. Edit your question and make it clear that this is an **option**, and not **needed**.

Comment: @Sneak I did see your answer just now. If Asi's collection view always has five items, then your answer could work well. If Asi always wants the last row to be centered, he may need a custom layout.

Comment: I don't understand why he would need that. He can just check if the section is the last section and return the insets accordingly? I'm not saying that your answer is wrong, but you are **misleading** the OP when you say that he **needs** to write a custom layout instead of providing your opinion as an **option**. Thats my point, if you are not sure that something **needs** to be done, don't say that it **needs to** , making the OP work hard for an easy solution.

Comment: @Sneak sure, that's one way to do it.

Comment: Hello my friends, sorry for the delay. I don't need ALAWAS 5 items, but when my data source arr count is 5 i need this cells order to be done. btw - if i'll have 2 elements only, i will need to center them as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this type of format in UICollectionView by changing the number of sections from 1 to 2.

And then you can define your custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout accordingly for different sections.

Comment: So you mean that i should store every 3 cells in section and play with it?